# Why in assigning a char array elements in c++, the assigned character is destroyed?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I wrote a function in C++ which removes two characters from a char array. I think when I assign `str[o+2]` to `str[o]`, the `str[o+2]` shoud not be changed. But when I use cout to print it, I see that `str[o+2]` is altered with null.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
void shiftLeft(char*,int, int);
int main(){
    char str[100];
    cout<<"enter the string: ";
    cin>>str;
    cout<<"removes the letter with index i and i+1\nenter i:";
    int i;
    cin>>i;
    int n=strlen(str);
    shiftLeft(str,i,n);
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
void shiftLeft(char*str,int i, int n){
    for(int o=i-1; o<n; o++){
        str[o]=str[o+2];
    }
}
```

For example with input `"abcdef"` and `i=3`, I expect output `"abefef"` but I get `"abef"`. where are the last `"ef"`? Why are they ignored?

Comment: If there is a null character at the end of the string, you want to make sure that doesn't get copied as well.

Comment: Try to debug this yourself first, this is really a very simple problem. A piece of paper and a pencil are most helpful here. Also read again the chapter dealing with strings in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: It's also undefined behaviour. With condition `o < n` the variable `o` gets at most `n-1`, the access `str[o+2]` then equlas `str[n+1]` which is out og bounds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
abcdef0???... <- the contents of array (0 means NUL, ? means indeterminate)
  ef0?        <- what is written to the position (shifted 2 characters)
```

Assigning `str[o+2]` to `str[o]` itself won't change`str[o+2]`,
but later `o` will come to `o+2` thanks to the `for` statement and then assigning `str[o+2]` to `str[o]` means assigning `str[o+4]` to `str[o+2]` with original `o` value.

Then, terminating null character is written and the string ends.